# What would a creature with very powerful and accurate throwing ability look like?

Tags: creature-design

In the world I'm building there is a very dangerous creature that can pick up rocks or any solid object and make them deadly projectiles by throwing it with high speeds and very accurately. By accurate I mean they can hit prey like a gazelle or deer from long distances (100+ meters distance) with high confidence, and even flying birds out of the sky (with skill). It's main mode of self defense is also throwing: it should able to make a split second decision and place an accurate headshot and incapacitate any charging predator (tigers, lions, etc).

Since this creature goes all in for powerful and accurate throwing ability, it has tradeoffs: it doesn't have and need fast locomotion as it can slowly creep up to its prey after the creature struck it dead. But this also its weakness: other throwing creatures or even its own kind can hit the creature easily. And that explains the evolutionary arms race: as the longer range and more accurate specimens have greater chance of survival against ones that doesn't throw that well, that's how the story goes.

So my question is: what kind of body features and senses this creature needs to have achieve all of this?

Comment: That creature sounds like a human being with a [sling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)#Combat).

Comment: *"It doesn't have and need fast locomotion as it can slowly creep up to its prey after the creature struck it dead":* and when finally arriving there it will find that its prey has been eaten by opportunistic hienas, vultures, and other carrior eaters.

Comment: I imagine it needs to be better than a human? Humans are exceptionally good at throwing things already. None are both as accurate and powerful as humans as far as I know.

Comment: Human body features. Humans are virtually the only creatures that can effectively throw. But it may not be physically possible to scale up to the ranges you want due to limits of biology and strength materials (your animal might have to be too massive to not collapse under its own weight or not destroy its own joints when throwing).

Comment: @AlexP "its prey has been eaten by opportunistic hienas, vultures, and other carrior eaters" Heh, then they'd get a rock in their head too, more stuff to eat.

Comment: @DKNguyen A small dense object like a rock can fly really long distances when thrown at an angle. An 50m/s initial speed 40° throw of a small spherical rock should fly about 175 meters far. About 50m/s is the fastest recorded speed a human could throw. But with a sling like or a throwing stick like appendage should allow this creature to reach 90m/s which should allow the creature to reach well beyond 300m. (I use this calculator: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/on4xzwtdwz) I'm mure curious about the precision and accuracy though, that's the hard part.

Comment: @Calmarius I don't think a sling is a fair comparison to a biological part since it's quite wheel-like and can be used to build up kinetic energy over time quite unlike the elastic energy storage of muscle. An atlatl would be a fair comparison though. When I mentioned biological limitations, I had in mind baseball players screwing up their shoulder. The precision and accuracy would be the harder part in practice, but is a lot easier to explain away in story since it's all a matter of vision and neural processing.

Comment: Personally, I think that throwing accurately at ranges of 100+ meters is unrealistic (borderline impossible) for non-tool assisted creatures. At those distances, thrown object aerodynamics become a significant factor, and it's unlikely that a creature would evolve which could repeatedly achieve accuracy unless your world has been saturated with identical, perfectly-formed golf balls for millions of years.

Comment: Humans are the best at throwing, bar none. Now, the *world record* for non-aerodynamic thrown objects is a bit north of 100 meters--104 meters for javelins. Simply make your creatures Olympian-class humanoids.

Comment: @Dragongeek That's a good point. Perhaps it produces them in its body and recovers them whenever it eats its prey.

Comment: What would an evolved atlatl (sic) look like?  An extra joint in the limb, and a very long arm?  If one of you folks promoting humans/apes go on to work a naturally evolved atlatl into your answer, you've nailed it.

Comment: @SurpriseDog there's also the [woomera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woomera_(spear-thrower)) of the Australian aboriginees, with which they can spear a Kangaroo that is bounding at full speed (50kph/30mph)

Comment: In "Braveheart" Wallace is unarmed [tm] and confronted in a village by armed English troops. There are numerous rocks to hand. Unfair match! :-).

Comment: Human beings are far, far, far and away the greatest animal at this, there's not even a close second.  We have been evolved from the ground up as the ultimate throwing robots.

Comment: Are you looking for strictly throwing, or are other mechanisms to create a projectile from a rock acceptable? Everyone has (rightly) pointed to humans as a prime example, and your definitions of distance/strength required lend to that - but wondering if you want extra-human capabilities?

Comment: Wouldn't a body plan optimized for throwing just be a human body plan? Pretty sure there is no other animal on the planet throughout history that can throw as powerfully and accurately as humans

Answer (score 49):

#### An optimal throwing animal? look in the mirror.

Or more precisely; A human whose practices their poi spinning, slinging, or is at least good at dancing, is the best throwing you'll ever see.

This picture is me poi spinning. There are two flaming balls circling around me fast enough that they blur in the camera shutter time. I have to move my wrists in a rhythm such that the chains holding the flaming balls don't intersect. There are no special effects or post processing.

[image]

(It's also my profile picture.... cause it's cool. But I digress.)

This rhythm is where a good throw comes from. A weight on a cord spun can be launched incredibly accurately and incredibly far. I witnessed an event at a circus training camp where people had to launch a spun poi (not on fire) across an oval and hit a 1m target on the other side. The best could hit a bucket sized target repeatedly.

I'm not this good, but I've watched people use spun poi to hit the middle of the square on a basketball backboard from out of bounds on the other side of the court. Repeatedly.

I cant find the documentary in which I saw this, but a surprisingly amount of our brain is dedicated to highly accurate throwing. The nerve impulse travels so slowly relative to the motion of our arms that our we need to queue signals in a buffer in our brains, and have multiple impulses in transit to the same muscle at once. This uses circuitry in the brain shared with dancing and rhythm that is very rare even in other primates.

The documentary I saw suggested that we evolved this highly accurate internal timer and event queue in order to throw accurately, and the success from throwing helped drive the evolutionary push towards bigger brains.

There's more to a good throw; we need the ability to pick up an object and guess its weight extremely accurately extremely quickly. Humans can get very good at this. I've witnessed retail workers reliably pickup customer orders of meats accurate to a few grams every time.

We need the ability to twist or spin our wrists just right, and time that spin very accurately, while also throwing. Curving paths, or stabilising spins take throwing to the next level. These are done in sports by humans all the time.

Throwing a heavy poi across an oval doesn't really utilise the full strength of the muscles, it uses the rhythm parts of your brain to build up the momentum and launch it. Errors in rhythm create imperfections in your spin, which lower your launch speed.

A trained human is an exceptionally good thrower, especially when we can create our own optimal tool of throwing, a sling, or weight on a stick. And to improve it, you don't need massive muscles, you need to tweak the brain to have even better rhythm than it currently does.

Your creature has a human or humanish brain, and exceptional rhythm.

Comment: "There are two flaming balls circling around me fast enough that they blur in the camera shutter time" Are you sure that's not just a long exposure?

Comment: The exposure is longer than a normal photo, yes. I don't know the exact settings as I didn't take it.

Comment: @Calmarius As a fellow poi spinner, I can confirm that, while that particular photo is long exposure, there is nevertheless significant blur over typical camera shutter times.

Comment: But still, balls of fire! Good note about the ability for humans to pick up on the weight and timings of an object very quickly.

Comment: It's not just the arms. Essentially our whole body evolved to be good at throwing things. We're so good at unconsciously calculating trajectories with a bit of practice that we do it for fun. We're so good at it, in fact, we don't even need to use our arms.

Comment: I'd dispute that we're optimal as a species, just very good (and, like with most things, we make tools to make us better). There's probably a far longer armed ape of some sort that would make a much better thrower, particularly if it has longer upper limbs than us. It might not still be able to beat us if we can use tools, though.

Comment: In his book of essays about science, "Unweaving the rainbow", Richard Dawkins suggests that one of the ways that speech might have evolved is connected to the chain of events necessary to throw something - hard, accurate throwing is, as you say, is a long and complicated process involving many different actions which need to sequence together perfectly, and he speculates that speech is like this too, and might have come from the same evolved mechanism, maybe even being a part of the throw itself - each step having it's own vocalisation perhaps.

Comment: @Calmarius Since I too play poi (DIY LED poi, though, not fire) and try some photography on that, I'd say the photo is taken with about 0.8 to 1.2s exposure time, corresponding to 3-5 full circles of the poi. With auto exposure timing of a smartphone cam, you'd see the flaming balls tracing maybe an eighth, maybe a quarter of a circle on the photo.

Comment: To be clear, an **untrained** human is an incredibly good thrower.  You don't need to qualify it as "trained".  Throwing is, indeed, one of the number of items in which we utterly, utterly dominate other animals.  Note that, obviously, we're "the opposable thumb animal" and that's precisely why we throw so well, along with 3 or so other resaons. Just as Max (via Dawkins!) points out, throwing is absolutely basic to our very evolution. Human throwing is like mentioning a bird's flight.

Comment: @lupe No creature on this planet can remotely approach the throwing accuracy of a completely untrained adult human, very few of them can get anywhere close to the speed, and none of them have the incredibly remarkable ability of being able to do it with essentially any object they can pick up. A human can pick up a rock, a stick, a rock tied to a rope, a ball, or a disc, and with no training or practice, hit a target the size of themselves at 20 paces with at least 50% accuracy. That's essentially a super power.

Comment: @Iron Gremlin I think you mistake what I mean - I think we're very good at throwing, but I could see a creature evolving that is better than us - there's a few specialized adaptions that would make us better. To start, the shoulder joint is sort of a problem. We can throw a lot, but eventually, it starts to get damaged - there are certainly adaptions that would help there

Comment: Adding an extra foot or two to our limbs, too, would be the equivalent of a spear thrower, for example - we'd get a lot more range. I honestly think the biggest issue with this creature evolving is the lack of good things to throw - rocks are good for driving things off, but less good for killing them, without a sling

Answer (score 33):

If you are looking for something other than an apelike creature, which other folks have rightfully pointed out would probably be the most straightforward answer, **might I suggest a creature akin so a sauropod with a long, immensely powerful and whip-like tail?**

In modern day, you can see tails being used as weapons by the komodo dragon, which can deliver powerful, stinging blows with its tail. If you were to make this tail prehensile (able to grip) or equip it with a scaly, scooping paddle, you could have the creature use it to launch projectiles at high speeds towards prey.

To have the attack be accurate at a distance, I think your creature would benefit from powerful binocular vision i.e. two forward-facing eyes. The better the vision, the better the aim!

I hope this helps give another option!

Resources:

- [Tails as weapons](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/phenomena/2014/01/18/tail-whips-and-face-bites/)
- [Komodo dragon using its tail as a whip (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQVJZzZ7tdY)
- [lizard using its tail to defend itself from leopards (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZ3C7srOMyc)
- [Binocular vision](https://connectusfund.org/7-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-binocular-vision)
- [Real animals with prehensile tails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehensile_tail)

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Unfortunately this suggestion doesn't answer the OP's question. This site is build around asking questions and providing answers. Posts that only provide commentary are likely to be deleted quickly.

Comment: @sphennings can you please explain how my response does not answer the OP's question? I am new and don't know how to message you directly. I'd like to make sure my post is useful to the OP.

Comment: @sphennings Everything he said answers the question of what features would be needed. the method of delivery? check, the required eyesight to aim? check. It has a lot of extra fluff that could be trimmed as the question doesn't ask for it but overall it answers.

Answer (score 9):

**Long armed ape**

I suggest that it is apelike possibly with one of its arms much longer than the other. This is how humans get maximum leverage when throwing.

Apes and monkeys already throw stones.

**Chimpanzee throws stones at spectators**  https://youtu.be/LbRFOPxrX8k?t=51

**Humans use arm extensions**

I can think of two main examples of making an arm extension, the throwing stick and the sport of pelota. A pelota player can project a ball at 200mph

**Throwing stick video** https://youtu.be/gfx6d-J8-oU?t=14

**Pelota video** https://youtu.be/d45uhH2l3xY?t=44

Given that rocks don't usually come in nice standard round shapes, the long arm must end in a hand.

**For those of you familiar with the sport of cricket, this orang-utan would make a formidable fast bowler.**

[image] [image]

Comment: This addresses the throwing strength part. I also wonder about the accuracy and precision part. As throwing strength doesn't worth much if it doesn't hit the target. The longest recorded basketball shot going through the ring is about 35 meters. At that distance most larger games will notice you and run away. I'd like to make this creature to be able to score a basketball shot from 100 meters or more, reliably (assuming there are no unforeseen things, such as wind gusts, or things like that).

Comment: @Calmarius For accuracy, the creature would definitely need a predator's eye arrangement with two forward-facing eyes for exact target triangulation. Furthermore, the eyes might be adapted to see clear at long distances like raptors or owls.

Comment: It's worth noting that orangutans and chimpanzes are pretty lousy throwers compared to humans despite their strength - a very long-handed ape would need all the biomechanical changes to wrists, shoulders and arms in which humans differ from apes; without human-like arms that orangutan would be a worse bowler than a random teenagr.

Comment: @Peteris -  True but then most apes don't live where there is an abundance of handy throwing-sized stones. Suitable environments might include stony beaches, riverbeds and the foot  of shale slopes. Evolution would be able to take its course in such places.

Comment: P.S. Apes also tend to live among trees and this is the worst place to do any kind of throwing. Just like humans they must have moved away from the trees before evolving this ability.

Comment: Apes and monkeys do throw stones, but they are **utterly useless* compared to us, Chas!  Much as apes/monkeys can walk "a bit" but we are flawless, apes/monkeys can throw "a bit".  We are throwing machines par excellence.

Comment: @Fattie - so you think these creatures should be modelled on ... what? Zebras? Remember that humans are also primates. I'm suggestion a creature that moved from the forest to a good stone-throwing environment and evolved the ability there.  I did not claim that modern-day apes were good at stone-throwing any more than modern-day humans are good a swinging through trees.

Comment: hi chas!  they should be modelled **on humans**

Comment: @Fattie - Okay, if you believe that, I suggest  you  submit it as an answer.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica - cheers!  in fact I wrote one of my usual long and bombastic answers already !  :)  just scroll ldown !!

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica in my answer I mention the four Factors that, you know, biomechanist-leaning roboticists and the like mention in relation to how good, indeed unique, humans are at this

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica (I just fully read your answer), regarding your two images, IMO the urangutan would be / is hopeless at bowling / throwing in general due to my points (1) and (2) {1 overwhelmingly; no opposable thumb, no even half-decent throwing}; point 3 I don't know (my guess is we are far better at 3 than all other primates); critical point 4 - primates have it to some extent but we have it much, much more refined.

Comment: BTW "This is how humans get maximum leverage when throwing."  I believe that is quite wrong (having read a little on sports throwing biomechanics, as I used to be in that entertainment field).  note that baseball picthers are faster than cricket bowlers. also, as I understand it, length-of-arm means little or nothing in baseball fastballs, it is apparently all about the "unwinding" motion of the gut-spine-area. if one just picks up a rock and throws it across the river (like Washington?!) you hardly use the length of your arms, it's all body...I believe

Comment: @Fattie - Fine, add that to your answer. I've made mine and I'm happy with it.

Comment: This reminds me of the Ape Titan from Attack on Titan, +1.

Answer (score 9):

I'd second the suggestion of a long armed ape, but perhaps with exceptionally elongated arm bones. These might look somewhat like a Kangaroo's back legs - very long, flat, and skinny, powerful tendons to adapt as shock absorbers, backed up by massive shoulder muscles. You'd expect to see adaptions to reduce the injuries baseball pitchers get, so, enlarged tendons, extra thick fluid sacs in the shoulder joints. It'll otherwise have a low center of gravity, to stop it toppling from its huge arms, with large, forward facing eyes. I'd guess they're also good at climbing trees, as this makes a good vantage point to hunt from. A good sense of smell, too, to track creatures it doesn't kill outright until their injuries prove fatal.

Human's big, neolithic adaption in throwing was the spear thrower - it is amazing how much futher you can chuck things with an extra foot extension on your arm.

Your creature is going to need something to throw, too. Rocks aren't going to be effective at killing stuff, and there's not piles of good throwing rocks everywhere. They also won't give it enough range.

I'd therefore suggest two plants it might have co-evolved with:

1. Mangroves - Mangrove seeds come as these kind of spear type shapes, designed to pierce the ground. In your world, I'd suggest the creature has a symbiotic relationship with a type of mangrove. This mangrove produces long, sharp, spears as seeds. These are broken off and thrown by the creature. This not only helps the plant with dispersal, but also provides it with a nitrogen rich growing site, if it does hit and kill a creature.
2. Bamboo - a mutation here might make the corms grow at an angle, allowing the creature to break off sharp bits just by snapping it. This is less fun than the bamboo example.

Answer (score 9):

If by "throwing" you mean "launching an accurate projectile", then contrary to most of the other answers here, I'm going to say limbs aren't necessarily the best way to do that.

Captive Octopii, I've heard, can quite accurately hit objects or people with jets of water they spray out of their tank.

So imagine a creature shaped like a bulbous but extremely muscular cylinder, at the center of which is a fluid-filled tube (I guess they live in a water-rich environment, to be able to replenish this easily).

Creature swallows projectile, positions it in tube, and then does a whole-body spasm, generating for a brief moment intense water pressure that launches the projectile just like a cannon would.  Aiming still requires a degree of skill, but very much less so than coordinating the multiple joins of a hand, arm, shoulder, and torso, as we do when we throw.

So, mostly it needs good binocular (or multi-ocular?) eyesight with widely spaced eyes to aim at its target accurately over long distances, and good proprioception to align its body accurately.  (Not "eyes on stalks" like a snail though, unless they're rigid - eyes that move relative to each other or to the creatures head would make accurate aiming very, very much harder).

Air based propulsion is also possible, especially if we're only considering lighter projectiles.  Even with our quite limited chest strength and lung capacity, humans can fire blow-gun darts 50 or 60 meters (according to the first couple of videos that came up on youTube when I searched, anyway), and we're in no way particularly evolved for that.  So 100m seems very reasonable for a large, powerful creature to launch small rocks or pebbles via gas or lung pressure, if specifically evolved to that task.

The key physiological trait would be a long, completely straight tube, that acts as the "gun barrel" for the projectile.

If it's inside the creature's body, surrounded by enormous compression muscles, then we might imagine a very heavy, long, lumbering, inflexible creature like a very elongated and stiff hippopotamus.  Perhaps on 6 or more stubby legs?  It's back-end and middle might be much larger than the front because that's where the most pressure needs to be.  And it would aim by positioning its whole body.

On the other hand, the firing tube could be more external, like some kind of protruding horn (using a horn would mean that the projectile would need to fit the bore quite closely, as horn isn't flexible, but maybe it can afford to be picky about the rocks it picks up... or maybe it grinds them down to the right size against each other in some kind of body cavity?).  I'm imagining something between a narwhal with legs, and a ridiculously exaggerated rhino (with a single very thick horn several meters long/high).

For smaller projectiles, wind speed might affect accuracy significantly, so these creatures might have large flexible spines or projections, covered in membranes or something like feathers, with which to sense the wind.  Perhaps running in a ridge along their backs, or protruding from their heads?

Also if you like, for greater lethality from smaller projectiles, perhaps the creature coats its projectiles in poison?  Curare-dipped darts worked for Amazon tribespeople, after all.

Comment: So basically a creature that can "sneeze" projectiles? Creative idea! +1

Comment: Come to think of it, it's been a long time since I saw the film, but didn't "Starship Troopers" have various castes of giant insect that were evolved or designed to launch projectiles somewhat in the way I'm describing?

Comment: And for additional reading : [Projectile use by non-human organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_use_by_non-human_organisms)

Answer (score 6):

I imagine that a creature optimized throwing would have arms like atlatls (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear-thrower)

That would be long, thin forearms with small hands/graspers on the end.  They would be arranged a little differently from ours.  With the arm in our natural "cocked hammer" position, you'd find the palm facing forward instead of to the inside.

The trick to throwing efficiently is getting the energy from your big and strong-but-slow muscles concentrated into a fast, small projectile.  At the end of the motion, everything that isn't moving slowly -- which necessarily includes any body part touching the very fast projection -- represents a waste of energy proportional to its mass, so this last link has to be lightweight.  That excludes tails or appendages made of muscle.

Atlatls are also pretty versatile.  You can use them like slings, pulling mostly perpendicular to the direction of motion, or more like the spear-throwing technique, applying force to the short end of a lever.  Also, of course, since they're stiff (unlike slings), the creature could put its little atlatl hands wherever it wants to pick things up.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is obviously humans, we utterly, utterly dominate the skill.

We're as far ahead of second place as birds are better at us than flying.

Some of the key points,

• the overwhelming issue is staggering, spectacular, just lights-out precision **control of your fingers**.  (Any baseball fan will explain this, or, watch *No No: A Dockumentary*)

Indeed, the fact that we're **the animals with opposable thumbs**, is 75% of the battle

• completely **upright stance**, that is to say, flawless balance on two limbs; your throwing limbs have to be specialized for throwing, **not something you "also walk on"** or "also swim with"

• adequate for the distances/speeds involved (ie, excellent) **depth perception and motion tracking** (many other animals crush us in these abilities, but ours are great)

• heavier-lighter-lighter limb design as you go outwards.  As any **robotic arm engineer** will tell you, it's incredibly hard to do **heavier-lighter-lighter-as-you-go-outwards** limb design.  Our arms, and dog's limbs, are just **utterly amazing** on this front.  Other animals (cows, elephants etc) less so as it's less important.

A great comparison is to look at monkeys/apes, who are completely useless at throwing, for exactly the four reasons above.

Answer (score 5):

Elephants also throw things like poo, mud, rocks, sticks, and tree trunks with their trunks.

Elephants are by far the strongest throwers on land.  War elephants have been trained to pick up horses and riders and throw them in the air.

I read in an article published in the Victorian era of a bull Asian elephant chasing people out of their village and then tossing their houses around - no doubt those were tiny one room wooden shacks.

So perhaps an elephant who could throw an object weighing hundreds of pounds ten feet should be able to throw an object weighing one pound hundreds or thousands of feet.

Elephants have rather poor eyesight, so their aim should be poor.  So giving an elephant like creature eagle eyes would be a good way to improve its long distance throwing accuracy.

Elephants are herbivores, and it would be unlikely for elephant sized creatures to be carnivores.  However, herbivores like elephants do sometimes attack other animals, and presumably your elephant shaped creatures could attack other animals by throwing things at them.

Furthermore, herbivores have been filmed eating smaller animals for unexplained reasons.

Possibly a large elephant like creature could get most of its calories from plant matter, but get some essential nutrients from meat, and thus sometimes hunt prey.

The more carnivorous you make you creature, the smaller it should be.  If it is totally carnivorous, it should be no larger than a lion, a tiger, or a polar bear.  In that case it would be much larger and stronger than a human, but much smaller and weaker than an elephant.  Thus its maximum throwing range should be somewhere between that of an human and an elephant - unless its throwing muscle in the trunk, head and shoulder are relatively stronger and larger than those of an elephant.

And if you make the elephant shaped carnivore even smaller, it should be even weaker and have a shorter throwing range, unless its throwing muscle in the trunk, head and shoulder are relatively stronger and larger than those of an elephant.

Comment: "perhaps an elephant who could throw an object weighing hundreds of pounds ten feet should be able to throw an object weighing one pound hundreds or thousands of feet." is not how it works; tossing heavy objects has different (contradictory?) requirements compared to flinging light objects at very high speed.

Comment: elephants however have really poor control of what they throw, and cannot throw very heavy things proportional to their mass.

Comment: "unexplained reasons?" - The default explanation for "why does animal X eat animal Y" is "for calories/nutrition." I don't think I've heard anyone say otherwise.  Plenty of herbivores are opportunistic carnivores.

Answer (score 4):

### Don't reinvent the wheel: Science and Nature

Humanity and science have found several ways to create long range weapons and tools which would be more or less viable in nature, depending on the environmental factors of the world. From rocks and sharpened sticks, to slingshots, catapults, guns (including water guns) and rifles.

Apes have already been mentioned, but there are also the [archerfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archerfish), some [spitting cobras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitting_cobra) and even frogs with their elastic [tongues](http://www.noel.gatech.edu/research/). While these real life examples don't match the criteria defined, they can give us some ideas on how to fulfill them.

### Criteria

##### Low mobility:

The reduced mobility of the creature will probably translate not only in a diminished sprinting speed but also in a slow turning ability. Because of this, it should have a way to **perceive** ―and not only react against― predators from different angles.

Eyes similar to **retractable telescopes** would achieve long distance perception and independent movement like that of a [chameleon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chameleon_vision) would help in both hunting and predator avoidance. This also does not hinder accuracy, as proven by said animals.

##### Projectile availability:

The availability of projectiles may be an issue, with rocks varying in shapes and sizes making accuracy at longer distances more difficult. Furthermore, in certain ecosystems, like a savanna, rocks may not be readily available.

Given the above, perhaps a self-produced projectile would be preferable. Manufacturing aside, I see three possibilities:

1. A fruit from a tree with a very tough, **round seed**. The fruit would contribute to the creature's nutrition while the latter would help the plant's spread. It may be digested into smaller shrapnel.
2. A hardened bullet made of **compacted dirt**, which would be shaped and solidified in its stomach.
3. A [pearl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearl)-like "**calcareous concretion**", similar to that of oysters. Note that these are susceptible to acid, however.

##### Shooting mechanism:

Long range weaponry is rarely suitable to close quarters which is why I'd suggest giving it different ways to attack and defend.

Its main hunting organ can be a **highly elastic and compressible tongue** with a cavity where a regurgitated seed/dirt (the pearl would need to come from somewhere other than the stomach) can be held in place and released. The mouth (or an inner bone structure) can be shaped as a gun barrel for higher effectiveness.

The secondary defensive organ can be a **flexible but strong tail-like excretory appendage**, with **compressed gas propulsion** (insert joke here) which can shoot seeds, pearls or other solids. This secondary mechanism could also be used to give the *coup de grâce* or death blow to a wounded ―yet still dangerous― prey.

##### Appearance:

This will depend on the surrounding environment, as with any other characteristic. We can imagine this creature as a reptilian, much like a chameleon or a Komodo dragon, with a longer, bigger tail. Or even an amphibian variety living in the swamps, with a lower firing range, perhaps. Also adding some **poison** may increase its deadliness without relying on raw kinetic energy. Since the creature is supposed to creep slowly to its prey, **camouflage** would help it close in till the target is in range.

###### A fun, perhaps less viable idea: a Solar Deathray

A flexible mirror or a series of smaller ones to concentrate solar radiation in a single point. Similar to a magnifying glass but with varying range. See this example in a question about [optics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10674/focusing-light-with-flat-mirrors) and its real life [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtzRAjW6KO0) demonstration (name taken from there). Range would not be an issue unless the atmosphere is unusually thick or the solar radiation is otherwise low. There is a [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491858/how-far-can-light-packets-of-photons-travel-on-earth-or-atmosphere) and a [blog](https://gravitationalballoon.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-far-can-light-travel-in-endless.html) entry on these topics which cover the technical aspects. However, we are considering distances of 100 meters whereas they are discussing kilometers.

Answer (score 4):

How about a creature similar to a chameleon:

[image: Chameleon]

that can also **spin** and throw an object super fast?

[image: Spinning bullet and a ball]

---

Chameleon's tongue is ultra quick with a crazy fast release (imaging 0 to 100 km/s in 0.01 seconds!). It has a telescopic mechanism for stretching/retracting. This provides both high speed and high accuracy for even catching the flying insects. And it has a sticky end for getting the prey to its mouth.

I can imagine a similar mechanism on a creature for doing the reverse: **throwing**. It picks up the rocks or other (small enough) objects with its "tongue", retracts it and then stretches it with deadly speed and releasing the object with the momentum.

For adding extra range (and accuracy), its tongue may also have the ability to give a spin to the projectile. Like the rifling in almost every modern gun.

---

*image credits: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19nRZ.gif) Science Llama [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm7sh.jpg) hunter-ed.com*

Comment: Good one, I also thought of a Chameleon!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest tool use as an essential part of adaptation for throwing.

Extending your arm by a few feet gives you huge advantages, as explained in other answers - either via slings, or spear throwers ... or even bows ... but leaves your excessively long limb highly vulnerable to injury or damage. Especially since it must be lightweight so that your throwing energy is concentrated in the projectile, not the limb.

If it's a vine or a stick on the other hand, just throw away the broken one and pick up a new one from your mangrove tree or bamboo clump. You have a huge advantage over anyone who has to wait for their throwing arm/tail/trunk to heal, or grow another one.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Maybe something like this little guy?